# How to use Fluent NHibernate Validator when using auto mapping?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent

I've just modelled a small database using Fluent nHibernate and the auto mapping feature.  Now I'm wondering how I work with validation.  In the past I've decorated my classes with attributes but the purpose of this by-convention automapping is to keep things clean.

I do have a couple override files which look like this:

```
public class EventMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Event>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Event> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(x => x.EventType, "TypeID").CustomType(typeof(EventType));
        mapping.Map(x => x.EventStatus, "StatusID").CustomType(typeof(EventStatus));
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.EventDates).KeyColumn("EventID");
    }
}
```

Is this where I would put my validation rules?  If so, what does that look like and is there really even a point to using the auto mapping (if my override files are going to be elaborate anyway)?

Thanks.

**To clarify further:**

My entities look like this as of now:

```
namespace Business.Data
{
       public class Event
       {
            public virtual int Id { get; set; }
            public virtual string Title { get; set; }
            public virtual EventStatus EventStatus { get; set; }
            public virtual EventType EventType { get; set; }
            public virtual IList<EventDate> EventDates { get; set; }
       }
}
```

I would like to keep them looking that like.  Just plain objects so in the future we can potentially switch out or upgrade the ORM and still have these nice clean objects.

However, when it comes to using [nHibernate Validator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/) (part of NHContrib) I'm not sure how to incorporate it without littering the properties with attributes.  I guess this is more of a question architecture.  I could use a different validation framework as well but I want it to be tied in with nHibernate so that it won't insert/update invalid records.  Any opinions appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by validation rules ? do you have an example ? I used the same as you in a project without validation as I don't understand the purpose really ? I could help you more if you try to be clear on that point

Comment: I guess I'm just asking what the "cleanest" way to incorporate nHibernate Validator is with a setup like this.  This post [link]http://marekblotny.blogspot.ca/2009/03/validation-of-nhibernate-entities.html shows how but in the end you have attributes decorating your objects.  Maybe that's the best way for now?  I'd like to leave the attributes out and specify the validation rules elsewhere.

Comment: I see now, my opinion is you should not use this and validate yourself before committing to the db. As this method is just throwing the error upper nothing more. It actually depend what project you are using if there is already validation just skip this. If not then yes use this but anyway that's not the place where you should set it. Attributes should be on your domain and the validator set up exactly at the same place where you set all your conventions just after really. read this for more informations.http://nhforge.org/wikis/validator/nhibernate-validator-1-0-0-documentation.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I just added to my question:  "I could use a different validation framework as well but I want it to be tied in with nHibernate so that it won't insert/update invalid records."  I'd really like to validation tied into nHibernate properly.

Comment: read my edit, domain =  entities. check my link Configuration part

Comment: I appreciate your answers but I'm not sure we're on the same page.  If I could summarize in one line:  "I would like use nHibernate Validator and define my validation _outside_ of my entity and *not* use attributes."  Maybe this just isn't how I should do it but I'm out here for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is :

Validation is part of the business at it depend from it and then the database scale to this need. So if you need a email string column in your db you should not rely on a db framework to do that especially as you said that may be later you will switch ORM then you will loose your work.

Keep validation in the business/high layer, and leave the db do simple query/insertion, remember NHibernate is already a bit complicate to hand on so keep it simple.

To answer your question, if you don't want to littering your entities use the xml validation as describe here.

http://nhforge.org/wikis/validator/nhibernate-validator-1-0-0-documentation.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I like your point.  I'm not a big fan of the XML validation so maybe I'll use Fluent Validation (http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) instead.  This will basically do what I want but won't be tied directly into nHibernate (which you convinced me is maybe a good thing).  I'll accept your answer shortly but I'd like to give time for others to answer.

Comment: no worries, just curious, what kind of application you are doing ? MVC ? Webform ? WPF ? WCF ?

Comment: Good question.  I'm using MVC 3.  It's a web application.  So I would like solid business-level validation that I can trickle down to the client as validation messages.

Comment: Then use the MVC Validation, it's rock solid and so good, where to put it will be your next question as it's attribute as well, and the answer will be on the ViewModel, as you want to validate a View. All your view should be strongly typed, always , always. that's the best place, there is some nice extensions as well like this http://dataannotationsextensions.org/ and probably more. Keep in mind that it will do as well javascript validation using jquery unobstructive (data attribute on each field), and you can create your own, so keep them for other project.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6 forget about Model, I hate this name it clash with db Model, I prefer ViewModel.